# Does the reaction given by Petyr Baelish exist in books ?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In Game of Thrones Season 5 Episode 4,

When Petyr Baelish and Sansa discuss about Lyanna Stark and Rhaegar Targaryen in the Crypts of Winterfell,

> Petyr Baelish gives surprised reaction when Sansa says Lyanna was kidnapped and raped by Rhaegar [at 2:25 in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bfnl9owFc84)].

It would be interesting to know if the same reaction is described in the books or not (if the scene exists in books)

> because it could give a positive hint for R + L = J theory to be true.

Is this scene described in the books?

If yes, how the reaction of Petyr Baelish is described?

Comment: This scene does not exist in the books, because neither Sansa nor Littlefinger went to Winterfell -- they went to the Eyrie. And never talked about Lyanna.

Answer (score 11):

First off, I think you might be reading a bit more into that scene than intended. Peytr's reaction isn't really one of surprise or denial, IMO. He might be thinking "I know something you don't", but he might just as well be thinking "sorry kid, kinda sucks to be you."

As far as this exact in the books, I definitely doesn't happen, since

> Sansa has never been back to Winterfell.

I don't remember the two of them ever talking about Rhaegar and Lyanna at any point, either, so I doubt any of this conversation came up. Much of what Peytr says to Sansa in that scene is dialogue borrowed from other conversations about the Tournament at Harrenhall (e.g. the Reed siblings tell Bran that same story early in *A Game of Thrones*.) I also don't know if any other character has insinuated *in-universe* that

> Lyanna went with Rhaegar willingly

but I think, for the reader at least, the subtext is so obvious it's barely even subtext anymore.

Comment: Wasn't there a conversation in ADWD... Can't even remember who it was now... That ambitious woman with the sop of a Frey husband, talking to Theon I think? Said something about L&R and the crypt? Or was it that savvy female Lannister cousin, who was talking to... Was it Jaime? So many minor characters, they all run into one in my head...

Comment: It's possible, but if so, it wasn't anyone as significant as Peytr (who might actually know something relevant)...

Comment: @user568458 The former is Lady [**Barbrey Dustin**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Barbrey_Dustin) talking to Theon in the crypts (although she's the widow of Lord Rodrik Dustin, not married to a Frey); the latter is Lady [**Genna Lannister**](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Genna_Lannister), Jamie's paternal aunt (*she* is in fact married to Emmon Frey).

Comment: a possible reason behind not describing this kind of conversation and reaction in the books, could be that it would have suggested/hinted that Lyanna went with Rhaegar willingly. While on the show, it was easier to divert our attention away from littlefinger (in fact he was out of focus/blurred when he gave this reaction). Either it's an intelligent thinking by makers of tv series or.... as u said i am reading bit more than intended.